# sfdx auth:web:login Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange in org

Tags: salesforcedx, professional-edition

I recently signed up for a Salesforce Professional Edition. But I can't authorize the org with sfdx. WTF ? In the [sales pitch](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/) it says with Profesional Edition you can have "Unlimited Custom Applications: build apps and customize Salesforce to meet your customers needs"
and it also says for 25$ extra I can have "Web Services API: Connect external systems and data to Salesforce using web services APIs, including REST, SOAP, and more." which I haven't purchased yet. Does that include sfdx ? Do I have to pay more to be able to build LWCs ?

When I do `sfdx auth:web:login` and succesfully login I get this message:

```
Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange in org: <orgid>.
Due to: Expected parsed JSON data to be an object
```

Is this a problem with sfdx or my professional Editiion org ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce CLI uses `REST` and `SOAP` [APIs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326486&type=1&mode=1) of the salesforce.

For Professional Edition these APIs are enabled at extra cost and you will need to request these throw your AE as documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326486&type=1&mode=1).

> Unlimited Custom Applications: build apps and customize Salesforce to meet your customers needs

The above means in your professional edition org you can install apps from AppExchange!

Comment: Ah ok https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yeLIAQ

Comment: Here it says that I can't develop in the Production Environment, which I think is what I'm in ? It says Profesional edition comes with one Dev Sandbox. Can I connect sfdx to that ? And how do I get my sandbox ?

Comment: You will create sandbox from prod! Try creating a sandbox from production environment